# Allow scrapy cloud to read seed list in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, scrapy

I'm trying to figure out a bucket policy to allow Scrapy Cloud to read my seeds list. I'm a bit confused as to whether I need an IAM policy specifically for this OR is a bucket policy sufficient?

I know when I create a bucket AWS by default makes the bucket non-public access (private). So how do I allow Scrapy Cloud to access my seed list on S3?

Comment: When you say "seeds list", is this a file that you store in S3 that contains a list of web URLs that Scrapy Cloud will download to drive its scraping activity? If so, unless Scrapy Cloud supports the notion of AWS credentials, you can create a (secure) pre-signed URL for the file or you could make the file public (insecure).

Comment: @jarmod - yes scrapy supports aws creds. scrapy can write results to s3 which I have setup and working. Its the seeds list that I'm having trouble with